# .NET / C# - Reflection Help - Classes in an Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, superclass

What is the best way to loop through an assembly, and for each class in the assembly list out it's "SuperClass"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(DataSet).Assembly; // etc
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.BaseType == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name + " : " + type.BaseType.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that generics and nested types have funky names, any you might want to use `FullName` to include the namespace.

Comment: Nope. Not homework. Survey my 201 questions - not a student. Just your average overworked / underpaid coder.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
  var isChild = type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(parentClass))
}
```

Reference from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx).

Comment: +1 - cool additional info. won't be testing Subclass/Superclass relationships on my current app, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) and [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx):

```
Assembly a;
foreach(var type in a.GetTypes()) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("{0} : {1}", 
            type.Name, 
            type.BaseType == null ? String.Empty : type.BaseType.Name
        );
}
```

Comment: Watch out; interfaces might not have a BaseType; nor "object"